# How do I select which remote vifm instance will run a command?

Tags: command-line, vifm

I run two separate instances of `vifm` on my machine:

```
$ vifm --server-list
documents
photos
```

In one I'm organising documents and in the other photos.  Sometimes I'm inside a third shell and would like to give commands to one of the `vifm` instances.  Had I only one instance I would do:

```
$ vifm --remote -c 'normal p'
```

But that does not allow me to select the instance I'm giving that command to.  The first instance (in asciibetical order, from what I tested) is always picked to run the command.  In other words, I cannot send commands to the `photos` instance.

How can I send a command to the `photos` instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify [additional argument](http://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm---server-name) you already know about (as you named your instances by using it):

```
$ vifm --help | grep -A1 server-name
  vifm --server-name <name>
    name of target or this instance.
```

Note this part:

> name of target ... instance.

In your case end command will look like the following:

```
$ vifm --server-name photos --remote -c 'normal p'
```

P.S. Option name is a bit confusing, but matches corresponding option of Vim.

Comment: Works like a dream, as a plus i learned something about `vim`'s `--servername`.